# How can I create a node with code inside of android studio using a firebase database reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

While I am certainly a beginner using android studio I am currently working on my own little project. It has both a working login and user registration system although upon entering the profile activity I create an object that I would like to get pushed into the database under the child "Users."

I have read through the Firebase documentation and learned how to read and write data but I don't quite understand how I can create nodes without manually pushing the + button in firebase and setting a name and value.

This is what my database looks like so far:
[What I would like to do is under the "Users: I would like to just have a node of each unique firebase user objects userID. Then inside of that the user object data that I have stored in my own object such as age, gender, firstName and lastname.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pqvK.png)

If this was included in documentation please leave a link as I would be more then happy to give it a re-read. I may have missed something and any/all help is much appreciated!

Here is what I have already tried with the outcome:

```
private void createUser()
{
    String first_name = firstName.getText().toString().trim();
    String last_name = lastName.getText().toString().trim();

    String gender = "";

    if (male.isChecked())
    {
        gender = "male";
    }

    if (female.isChecked())
    {
        gender = "female";
    }

    //int years = Integer.getInteger(age.getText().toString());

    User user = new User(first_name, last_name, gender, 18, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").setValue(user);
}
```

Outcome:
[Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5clEI.png)

The outcome that I am working towards is one where you just see the User Id's generated by firebase inside the "Users" node and then inside each one of those the user object that I create in the createUser() method.

Comment: Without seeing what you've already tried, it seems unlikely that someone will do a better job than the Firebase documentation at explaining how to read and write data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 1):

With users child path append your uid like this "Users/" + uid and then set the value. It will create a new node for every unique user.

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
 User user = new User(first_name, last_name, gender, 18, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users/" + uid).setValue(user);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!